# Problems accessing Activity and Mailings

Tags: activities, error, mailing, core

CiviCRM 4.7.11
WordPress 4.6.1

Having problems accessing Activities and Mailings.

1. From a Contact record, click "Activites" and get an Invalid JSON response. See image.
2. From a Contact record, click "Mailings" and get the Summary of the record.

Can't do "Find Activities" or "Find Mailings" from Search pull-down either. "Find Mailings" goes to the dashboard.

Can use Custom Searches and Activity Search. So doesn't seem to be a database error. Seems to be a code error. Haven't done any upgrades.

[image: Invalid JSON]

[image: Find Activites]

Did research on the JSON error and this seems to be the code that is causing the error.

> CRM.$(function($) {   // The set of options we can use to initialize
>   jQuery.dashboard().   var options = {
>   
>       widgetsByColumn: [[{"id":2,"name":"getting-started","title":"CiviCRM
>   Resources","url":"\/wp-admin\/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm\/dashlet\/getting-started&reset=1","cacheMinutes":"7200","fullscreenUrl":"\/wp-admin\/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm\/dashlet\/getting-started&reset=1&context=dashletFullscreen"}],[]],
>   
>       // These define the urls and data objects used for all of the ajax requests to the server.
>       ajaxCallbacks: {
>   
>         // jQuery.dashboard() POSTs the widget-to-column settings here.
>         // The 'columns' property of data is reserved for the widget-to-columns settings:
>         //    An array (keyed by zero-indexed column ID), of arrays (keyed by widget ID)
>         //    of ints; 1 if the widget is minimized.  0 if not.
>         saveColumns: {
>           url: '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/ajax/dashboard',
>           data: {
>             // columns: array(0 => array(widgetId => isMinimized, ...), ...),
>             op: 'save_columns', key: "6318f73741bb1ff8ca4f6bdb6a720062"
>           }
>         },
>   
>         // jQuery.dashboard() GETs a widget's settings object and POST's a users submitted
>         // settings back to the server.  The return, in both cases, is an associative
>         // array with the new settings markup and other info:
>         //
>         // Required properties:
>         //  * markup: HTML string.  The inner HTML of the settings form.  jQuery.dashboard()
>         //    provides the Save and Cancel buttons and wrapping  element.  Can include
>         //    s of any standard type and s, nested in s etc.
>         //
>         // Server-side executable script callbacks (See documentation for
>         // ajaxCallbacks.getWidgets):
>         //  * initScript:  Called when widget settings are initialising.
>         //  * script:  Called when switching into settings mode.  Executed every time
>         //    the widget goes into settings-edit mode.
>         //
>         // The 'id' property of data is reserved for the widget ID.
>         // The 'settings' property of data is reserved for the user-submitted settings.
>         //    An array (keyed by the name="" attributes of s), of  values.
>         widgetSettings: {
>           url: '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/ajax/dashboard',
>           data: {
>             // id: widgetId,
>             // settings: array(name => value, ...),
>             op: 'widget_settings', key: "6318f73741bb1ff8ca4f6bdb6a720062"
>           }
>         }
>       }
>   
>     };
>   
>     var dashboard = $('#civicrm-dashboard')
>       .on('mouseover', '.widget-header', function() {
>         $(this).closest('.widget-wrapper').addClass('db-hover-handle');
>       })
>       .on('mouseout', '.widget-header', function() {
>         $(this).closest('.widget-wrapper').removeClass('db-hover-handle');
>       })
>       .dashboard(options);
>   
>   
>     $('.crm-hover-button.show-refresh').click(function(e) {
>       e.preventDefault();
>       $.each(dashboard.widgets, function(id, widget) {
>         widget.reloadContent();
>       });   });
>   
>   });
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>       function createSWFObject( chartID, divName, xSize, ySize, loadDataFunction ) {
>          var flashFilePath = "/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/OpenFlashChart/open-flash-chart.swf";
>   
>          //create object.
>          swfobject.embedSWF( flashFilePath, divName,
>                            xSize, ySize, "9.0.0",
>                            "expressInstall.swf",
>                            {"get-data":loadDataFunction, "id":chartID},
>                            null,
>                            {"wmode": 'transparent'}
>                           );
>       }   OFC = {};   OFC.jquery = {
>              name: "jQuery",
>                image: function(src) { return ""},
>                popup: function(src) {
>                var img_win = window.open('', 'Save Chart as Image');
>              img_win.document.write('Save Chart as Image' + OFC.jquery.image(src) + '
>   ');
>              img_win.document.close();
>                          }
>                    }
>   
>   function save_image( divName ) {
>         var divId = "" ? 'open_flash_chart_'+divName : "";
>             if( !divId ) {
>                  divId = 'open_flash_'+divName;
>           }
>         OFC.jquery.popup( divId ); }
>
> Configure Your Dashboard
>
> Refresh
>   Dashboard Data
>
> Welcome to your Home Dashboard
>           
>               Your dashboard provides a one-screen view of the data that's most important to you. Graphical or tabular data is pulled from
>   the reports you select, and is displayed in 'dashlets' (sections of
>   the dashboard).
>
> Javascript must be enabled in your browser in order to use the dashboard features.
>
> CRM.$(function($) {
>       $('#crm-dashboard-configure').click(function(e) {
>         e.preventDefault();
>         $(this).hide();
>         if ($("#empty-message").is(':visible')) {
>           $("#empty-message").fadeOut(400);
>         }
>         $("#civicrm-dashboard").fadeOut(400, function() {
>           $(".crm-dashboard-controls").hide();
>           $("#configure-dashlet").fadeIn(400);
>         });
>         CRM.loadPage(CRM.url('civicrm/dashlet', 'reset=1'), {target: $("#configure-dashlet")});
>       });   });

Comment: you can Accept your own answer and keep SE happy by having more 'answered' questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by re-installing CiviCRM. Somehow it got corrupted.